# How to create Busuu daily reminder notification on firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a language learning app and I want to send daily reminders like Busuu.

[image]

The word to be sent will be different each day and it will be a word from the user practiced vocabulary. (for the next 5 days of no activity on the app)

How can I achieve that using firebase? I think that I can store on Firestore the last session time and a list of 5 words of the last practice and use a function with a crown job to get the users that are no active specific time(1-5 days) and send the notification with the corresponding word. I don't know if it is the best approach.

Comment: Using a 'cron' job is the approach. Give it a try and let us know when you get stuck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use cloud functions and cron jobs. Watch this video for getting started
[Timing Cloud Functions for Firebase using an HTTP Trigger and Cron - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=7)

Same with above, but using `pub-sub event`. And the cron job using google app engine. The step by step guide, can be found [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html)